# How can I add a 3d wave texture to a flat surface to represent water?

Tags: texturing

I am completely new to Blender and having some difficulty solving a problem. I am creating a map with textured surfaces. These are meant to be tactilely different. Meaning feel different to the touch. I used the wave texture over a section that represent a water body. I like the look of it but I need to create raised surfaces along the texture that align with the peaks of the waves. As it is now the texture is simply visual and completely flat. Is this possible? If not can you give another suggestion of a texture I could use that might "feel" like a wave to the touch. I used the voronoi texture for the land surface and don't want them to be too similar.

Comment: The texture can be used for Displacement, but the plane will need more geometry so that the texture has actual vertices to move